# Somehow a folder on my MS Outlook got deleted

Tags: email

Here's the problem:
somehow a folder on my MS Outlook got deleted (don't ask...)
Fortunately, Outlook compacts and stores all the info from inbox, sent, and all folders.
This is saved as a DBX file under "Documents and settings / owner / local settings / application data / identities / (identity)

I can find these files, but how do I restore them?
I cannot import or export them.
Is there a way to restore / convert or other?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User http://superuser.com/tour. Consider deleting this question. As it stands now it can only gather downvotes which impacts your ability to ask questions. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recover your email do the following

1. Sign in to your Outlook.com account (via a Computer/Laptop)
2. Go to your Deleted folder (found on the left pane under Folders)
3. Look for "Lost a message?", and click "recover deleted messages"

For more: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/deleted-dbx-files-want-to-restore/Mg9-5RTzCR8